# Recording video in Safari using WebRTC or RecordRTC

Tags: safari, webrtc, recordrtc

Is it possible to record video on Safari browser using WebRTC or RecordRTC. I tried testing sample links of their API, works well on Chrome and Firefox, doesn't work on Safari. (I tested on Mojave / Safari 12 ). Here are the links I tried but doesn't work:

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/

https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that safari doesn't support `MediaRecorder` by default, so we can't record video by using webRTC or `RecordRTC`.

I am still investigating on it...

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Also looking for a solution on Safari